# take long time installing and updating packages by wget on arch linux

Tags: wget, archlinux

I don't know why, when im downloding  or installing or updating package, download speed is very slow?
and take very long time!!!!

when im working in windows my download speed is 1M but in arch is changable ,is between 50k to 100k?
im using wget in [pacman.conf](https://ptpb.pw/LCte)

I use [reflector](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Reflector) but it had nothing changed and my package download speed is to slow.
    `can i create list from pacman update package and then download those from windows and again install all packages in Arch?`

Answer (score 0):

1. Check out your network settings,`ip` `dns` `route`...  sometimes this will solve download speed problem.
2. Find the fastest mirror.

   ```
   $ cd /etc/pacman.d/     
   $ cp mirrorlist mirrorlist.bak    
   $ rankmirrors -n 6 mirrorlist.bak > mirrorlist
   ```
3. Check mirrors status https://www.archlinux.org/mirrors/status/.

You can see more from [Archwiki Mirrors](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/mirrors).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider reading the documentation about *pacman* performance [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman/Tips_and_tricks#Performance).

---

You can manually force *pacman* to refresh the package lists (mirror list) with:

```
pacman -Syyu
```

---

To answer your question about downloading out of arch, the first part of the following will be with [laverna](http://laverna.cc) which is a software I maintain on [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/laverna/), and the second part will be with a package in official repository.

## AUR

### Download

We have 2 solutions:

1. Use **git**
2. Download snapshot

***Using Git***

Clone in the current folder the repository with

```
git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/laverna/ .
```

***Using Snapshot***

Just wget the snapshot or download directly with the browser.

```
wget https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/snapshot/laverna.tar.gz
```

## Official Repositories

You can easily get a download link the package web page.
For example with `sqlite-doc` the web page link is [here](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/sqlite-doc/) and the download link (from a mirror) is [here](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/sqlite-doc/download/).

### Back to Arch

Then back to arch, we have to build and install packages. To do so we navigate to the folder where you cloned/downloaded the package (cf. `cd`)  then execute the following to build.

***(Only if `packageName-version.pkg.tar.xz` doesn't exist)***

```
makepkg
```

Finally, after `makepkg` you obtain a file in the current directory which is in our AUR example `laverna-0.7.4-RC1-linux-x64.pkg.tar.xz`.

To install the `packageName-version.pkg.tar.xz` file we just have to execute the following and answer the questions as usually.

```
sudo pacman -U laverna-0.7.4-RC1-linux-x64.pkg.tar.xz
```